# floating part of a ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a fairly basic question.

I have a page with a ul with 7 lis, spanning 100% of the page. I want to make the last three lis float to the right, and I want the very last one to be a different color. I am trying not to recode this more than necessary.

Here is the code, how shall I apply the css? Make another ul, (but would it stay in line with the other) or apply to the li directly? can I make a special class of li to let those last three be positioned in a different place?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ul {
        width:100%;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        list-style-type:none;
      }
      a {
        width:6em;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:white;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link five</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link six</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link seven</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give the li classes, i think that might be the simplest yet most effective way. It's better than creating a different ul for every li you want different.

Comment: @Déjà vu, yeah seeing as how last-child has no support in IE, I think the li classes probably will work best. Someone below said apply the css to the links themselves too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `:nth-child()` for this. [css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

```
li:nth-child(5),
li:nth-child(6),
li:nth-child(7) {
    text-align: right;
}

li:nth-child(7) a {
    color: red;
}
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/3RR8D/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
  <li><a class="float" href="#">Link five</a></li>
  <li><a class="float" href="#">Link six</a></li>
  <li><a class="float" id="last" href="#">Link seven</a></li>
```

css

```
.float{
float:right;
}
#last{
color:red;
}
```

Comment: it's `#last` in your css since it's an ID

Comment: sorry didnt mean that

Comment: shouldn't you change it? or change the class to: class="float last" so it gets both classes. You should edit it so if he tries this at least it works =]

Comment: ye srry  got distracted

Comment: This looks pretty easy, I think I will go with this first.

Comment: Oh two classes on one <a>! That's fabulous!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code without adding another list or classes.

```
li:nth-child(4) ~ li {text-align: right;} /* or float? */
li:last-child a {color: green;}
```

Comment: `:nth-last-child(3)` would be better "to make the last three lis float to the right".

Comment: text-align on a li aligns the text inside the li, not the li itself.

Comment: @Rudie: with nth-last-child you're right. float vs. text-align, LIs has no width, with float they will be side by side (if you don't add width or clear). I think RhZ meant text-align, but into a comment I added `float`.

Answer (score 0):

you need this

```
li:nth-child(6)  {
        text-align: right;
      }
      li:nth-child(7) a {
        color: red;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

> (the rule would applies regardless of how many "li" will be)

```
li:nth-last-child(1), li:nth-last-child(2), li:nth-last-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}
li:last-child{
color: red;
}
```